Remove console logs from CRA in production server
I wanted to remove all the logs in the production server for two main reasons: One is to try reducing the overall bundle size and other is to make the logging clean in the main website(there are literally a LOT made till now for different components)
Is there a quick and easy way to do this?
I have tried out these steps:

Modify the console function to do nothing:

if (process.env.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT === 'PRODUCTION') {
  console.log = function () { };  
}

I added this in the root index.js file. Strangely, this did not work for me after rebuilding the app and I could still see all the logs.

Tried installing the babel-remove-console package

npm install babel-plugin-transform-remove-console --save-dev

However, this step required me to run the npm run eject function which was permanent and I was hesitant to do that (just an intern and I definitely don't want to ruin the entire website).
